# Android Studio - undefined label: 're'

Tags: android

I'm wondering how to make this break statement working ??
i have looked in every site but nothing worked with it, here is the code :

```
    public void check_if_connected(Socket sock){
    re:
    if (sock.isConnected() == false){

    }
    break re;
    }
```

it says : Undefined label: 're'.

[image: here an image for the code and how it looks with error]

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with this statement?

Comment: back to 're' because i will make a thread with this void that will loop again and again if it find that socket is disconnected it stop

Comment: that is not how a label works.

Comment: @njzk2 thank you for helping if you have any idea about goto statement for android that will be great , cause i will use it in catch to get back before try statement.

Comment: `goto statement`: simple, don't do it. ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` labels are not used like `goto`s they are used to specify which level of looping to break to.

In this case your break and label are at the same depth. An example of a place where you would use a label, is something like:

```
while(condition1){

    breaktohere:
    while( condition2 ){

         while(contition3){

              if(somebreakcondition){
                  break breaktohere; // breaks out of 2 while loops
              }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you for explanation , but how to make it work like goto or what can i use like goto ??

Comment: Based on the comment on your question, i think what you are trying to acheive is `while(sock.isConnected()){ /*your code here*/}` This will loop until you are disconnected.

Comment: If you ever find yourself doing this, stop, think again, and come up with a better design.  The code above is ffffuuuggggllllyyyy.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!sock.isConnected()){

}
```